# Not able to upload using PhpStorm

Tags: php, file-upload, ftp

I am trying to upload my site contents using PhpStorm. FTP connection supported at my website is as follows:

```
Host: ftpes://x.y.z.u
Username: username
Password: passwd
Port no 21
```

I have configured my PhpStorm as follows:

[Ftp Server connection configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ecJyD.png)

Here I am able to successfully connect with server. But when I am trying to upload any file, I am getting following exception:

**Failed to transfer file '\tests\ExampleTest.php': could not create FTP directory "ftps://207.174.215.236/tests".**

After this I enabled passive mode as follows:

[Passive mode configuration at PHPStorm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1jqGx.png)
Then again I tried to upload my file, but the upload process couldn't be completed. I got following exception in my log file:

```
2016-09-11 12:08:21,135 [ 783522]   INFO - ains.plugins.webDeployment.ftp - java.net.SocketException: Connection closed by remote host 
2016-09-11 12:08:26,521 [ 788908]   WARN - t.connections.RemoteConnection - Retrying connecting to ftps://x.y.z.u:21/ in @f3d492: 1 iterations 
org.apache.commons.vfs2.FileSystemException: Could not list the contents of folder "ftps://x.y.z.u/".
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.AbstractFileObject.getChildren(AbstractFileObject.java:1173)
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.ftp.FtpFileObject.getChildren(FtpFileObject.java:445)
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.AbstractFileObject.getChild(AbstractFileObject.java:1095)
    at com.jetbrains.plugins.webDeployment.connections.RemoteConnectionPool.createConnection(RemoteConnectionPool.java:188)
    at com.jetbrains.plugins.webDeployment.connections.RemoteConnectionManager.openConnection(RemoteConnectionManager.java:114)
    at com.jetbrains.plugins.webDeployment.PublishUtils.lambda$null$0(PublishUtils.java:102)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$2.run(ApplicationImpl.java:307)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPConnectionClosedException: Connection closed without indication.
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.__getReply(FTP.java:317)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.__getReply(FTP.java:294)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.getReply(FTP.java:692)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient.completePendingCommand(FTPClient.java:1813)
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.ftps.FTPSExtendedClient.initiateMListParsing(FTPSExtendedClient.java:127)
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.ftps.FTPSExtendedClient.mlistDir(FTPSExtendedClient.java:99)
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.ftp.FtpJBHelper.listFiles(FtpJBHelper.java:66)
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.ftp.FTPClientWrapper.listFilesInDirectory(FTPClientWrapper.java:170)
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.ftp.FTPClientWrapper.listFiles(FTPClientWrapper.java:152)
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.ftp.FtpFileObject.doGetChildren(FtpFileObject.java:135)
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.ftp.FtpFileObject.doListChildren(FtpFileObject.java:461)
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.AbstractFileObject.getChildren(AbstractFileObject.java:1164)
    ... 11 more
```

Please guide me how I can upload my file.

I am able to upload my file using filezilla and winscp, but not able to upload it using PhpStorm.

Comment: Have you tried connecting via an FTP client to test that the FTP service is running correctly?  As a wild guess I would say your target server isn't configured correctly/user doesn't have permissions to where you are trying to write the file.

Comment: Yes, I am able to connect using filezilla and winscp. Even I am able to send and receive files via these two applications.